# Checking data in the form not be empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, validation

in the view (form) I check the data to be not blank (empty in php:))
but what I am doing is ugly:

```
<% if request.post? %>
<% if @ticket[:name].blank? %>
<% style="fieldWithErrors" %>
<% else %>
<% style="field" %>
<% end %>
<% if @ticket[:department_id].blank? %>
<% style1="fieldWithErrors" %>
<% else %>
<% style1="field" %>
<% end %>
<% else %>
<% style=" " %>
<% style1=" " %>
<% end %>
```

as default the style of inputs must be "" if the data are submitted there are checked not be blank, all these spoil the form, so where its should be placed in a project and how its do in the correct way?

Comment: is it a part of code from your view ?

Comment: yes! I have validation in  the model, but have problen in the view

Answer (score 0):

Put your verification stuff in your model. Check this out: http://thelucid.com/2010/01/08/sexy-validation-in-edge-rails-rails-3/ it has everything you need

Comment: yes. i do so in my model, but the code mentioned above consider for the css part...